PowerBI: Flexibly calculate delta from different status/date
I need to show in my dashboard the delta of the same values (Sales, Cost, Profit) for different quarters (stored as date = last date of the quarter).
Let's say I want to have 2 slicers to compare the Sales/Cost/Profit of the Q1 2023 (selected in 1. Slicer) to Q3 2023 (selected in 2. Slicer) and then change the value in slicer 2 to Q1 2024 date.
The calculation of the delta will be done as a messure and shown in a card. How can I apply my messures to change with the slicer/dropdown selection?
Thanks and have a nice day!

pls provide some sample data and expected output
